# How to use putString() method in pyrebase (Python) Firebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, storage, pyrebase

I want to put a **uri image** directly to firebase storage, **no convert** image. I have read about `putString()` in JS

```
var message = 'data:text/plain;base64,5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
ref.putString(message, 'data_url').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
});
```

Does `pyrebase(python)` have any method like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's own Storage SDKs have a `putString` method, which takes a base64 encoded string and writes the decoded binary contents of that to a file on disk. I don't see such a method in Pyrebase's docs on [accessing Storage](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#storage) though.

As far as I can see in Pyrebase's [implementation of `put`](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L384-L407), it uses the [gcloud library](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html) to implement its Storage handling, so you could check that SDK too to see if it supports direct base64 uploads.